# Finding tex packages with a local texlive installation

Tags: texmaker, installing, texmf-local

I installed texlive locally following [this](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html):

I added to *.bash.rc*:

- `export PATH="/my/texlive/install/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"`
- `export MANPATH="/my/texlive/install/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH"`
- `export INFOPATH="/my/texlive/install/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH"`

I tested:
`which pdflatex` and it gave me the correct executable in my local installation folder.
Now I installed texmaker via `sudo apt install texmaker`, but when I try to compile a tex file it says that `algorithm.sty` is not found.

`algorithm.sty` is definitely inside `/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms` but texmaker seems to be unable to find it.

I also tried to define the `TEXINPUTS` in my `.bashrc` variable via:

`export TEXINPUTS=.:~/my/texlive/install/texmf-dist//:`

But still, texmaker is unable to find algorithm.sty. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

**EDIT:**

Okay it seems, that I have 2 installations `which -a pdflatex` gives me the local path AND `/usr/bin/pdflatex` how can I get rid of the second one? I somehow fixed it replacing the commands used in texmaker's options to the full local path...

Comment: Probably, your texmaker have a full path for pdflatex in its settings. Look if something like `/usr/bin/pdflatex` is used as a compiler.

Comment: where would I see this? In options --> configure Texmaker there are no full paths. For example Latex: ```latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex```

Comment: Then I don't know what happens. Did you log out and then log in back to make your updated environment variables propagate to all programs?

Comment: I used `source ~/.bashrc` but I also did a restart now and it still does not work

Comment: How exactly are you starting texmaker? Menu, doubleclick file? In that case `bashrc` is not enough. texmaker never gets into contact with anything bash. Add it you your `.profile` as well, then log out and in again.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much!

Comment: This is sadly a very common error. Where exactly did you get the information that the PATH change to be added to bachrc (if I may ask)

Comment: I extended the PATH before like that. It was told to me long ago from a friend who introduced me to the world of ubuntu. This time I just used google and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path) and completely ignored the .profile answer because I was looking for .bashrc and found it in the second answer... I did not even know that .profile exist and what it is.